# How to determine the reflection point on an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, reflection

Here is my problem. There are  two points P and Q outside an ellipse, where the coordinates of the P and Q are known. The shape of the ellipse is also known. A ray comming from point P is reflected by the ellipse and arrivates at Q. The question is how to determine the reflection point on the ellipse. I mean is there any analytical method to calculate the coordinate of the reflection point?

[image]

Comment: If M is the required point, Angle PMQ is a local maximum.

Comment: The major, minor axes of ellipse and inclination to an arbitrary line like x-axis are known?

Comment: Yes, they are pefectly known.

Comment: Is the new method and results it produced acceptable ?( including when P,Q are inside the ellipse in general),

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

We can use a method similar to that of Max Payne, but representing the ellipse by its parametric equations $x = a \cos t$, $y = b \sin t$. By differentiation, the tangent vector is $(- a \sin t, b \cos t)$, hence the normal vector $(b \cos t, a \sin t)$.

Now we express the equality of the angles to the normal, by the equality of dot products

$$\frac{(P_x - a \cos t) b \cos t + (P_y - b \sin t) a \sin t}{\sqrt{(P_x - a \cos t)^2+(P_y - b \sin t)^2}} = \frac{(Q_x - a \cos t) b \cos t + (Q_y - b \sin t) a \sin t}{\sqrt{(Q_x - a \cos t)^2+(Q_y - b \sin t)^2}}.$$

This can be rewritten as a nasty trigonometric polynomial of degree four by squaring and reducing to the common denominator, then rationalized to an octic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You could orient the coordinate system to prefer the ellipse. That is, take your original coordinate system, and find the translation that moves the ellipse origin to the center. And find the rotation that aligns the ellipse axes with the coordinate axes. Apply these to $P$ and $Q$, so now the problem is...

We have an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and points $P'=(h,k)$ and $Q'=(m,n)$. Where is the point $M'$ on the ellipse such that the ray $P'M'$ reflects to $Q'$?

The ellipse edge is traced by $r(t)=(a\cos(t),b\sin(t))$. At $t$, the tangent vector is $\vec{u}=\langle -a\sin(t),b\cos(t)\rangle$.

At $t$, the line from $P'$ has direction $\vec{v}=\langle a\cos(t)-h,b\sin(t)-k\rangle$.

At $t$, the line from $Q'$ has direction $\vec{w}=\langle a\cos(t)-m,b\sin(t)-n\rangle$.

The relationship between these three vectors needs to be that the sum of normalized $\vec{v}$ and normalized $\vec{w}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{u}$. That is: $$\left(\frac{\vec{v}}{\lVert\vec{v}\rVert}+\frac{\vec{w}}{\lVert\vec{w}\rVert}\right)\cdot \vec{u}=0$$

That sets up a polynomial equation in $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$, where you could solve for $t$. There may be multiple solutions, some of which correspond to a ray that passes into the ellipse and reflecting from the inside. After finding $t$, that tells you $M'$. And then you can undo the original coordinate transformation to answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be as follows:

Let $\rm P{(x_1,y_1)} \ Q{(x_2,y_2)}, and\  R{(h,k)}, $ be the points.

Let ellipse ($\rm S$) be a special ellipse with centre (0,0)

$$\begin{align}\rm S &=\rm \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+ \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \\
\rm Equation \ of \ tangent\ at\ R &:\rm \dfrac{xh}{a^2}+ \dfrac{yk}{b^2}-1 = 0  \ \ \ \ \ \ ... (i)\end{align}$$

Since the line segment $\rm PR$ (slope $\rm m_2$) is equally inclined to the tangent ( slope $\rm m_1$) as the segment $\rm QR$ ( slope $\rm m_3$), we can equalise the angles.

[image]

$$\rm\tan\theta=\dfrac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$$

$$\rm\tan\phi=\dfrac{m_1 - m_3}{1+m_1m_3}$$

$$\rm \implies \tan\theta = \tan\phi \ \ \ \ \ \ ... (ii)$$

Find $\rm m_1, m_2, m_3$

You'll get $2$ equations with $2$ unknowns $\rm h$ and $\rm k$.

---

**Note** In my answer, I used eqn of standard ellipse with centre at origin. But this method will work for any ellipse. For finding tangent eqn, just put $T=0$

---

**EDIT**

Here is a graph which shows tangent, and a line inclined equally to it (it tangent is the angle bisector of the lines.) : **[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4ftgi2y8cj)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim. The equations are correct. But soving the two equations seems to be not a easy work.

Comment: @Wang thats why i left it for you ;) it was becoming complex. I don't know if that would be applicable here, but there is a property of reflected path that it is the shortest possible.I hope there is a shorter method.

Comment: @Tim You have not fully given answer for the question. Coordinates of R are not expressed  in terms of P, foci/ center or Q . You have mentioned basis for it.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes i have not given the full answer. but wait this isn't an exam right? I gave the equation which will yield the coordinates.

Comment: The incident and reflected rays at external and internal situations are symmetrical with respect to ellipse normal. There is no reason why that there should be symmetry with respect to the tangent as well. This *hasty* ( low level &  jumpy :( ) assumption lead to my error that I only  now  realized . .. Mea culpa. I have however not so far got any  pin-pointed  comment  as to the source of this error. The result of reflection law is valid for *all* smooth curves whose proof is given in text-books  of variational  calculus , not  just for this ellipse alone, but like not to reproduce it here..

Comment: @Narasimham But i do think that the other method that you mentioned, of minimising the path length, can be used here. If it is a standard ellipse, then we can use the parametric coords $(a\cos \theta, b \sin \theta)$ and minimise the length of path using distance formula. If it is not a std. ellipse, then i dont know what will be parametric coords. But he method is good.But i am unaware of Lagrangian that you mentioned in your post.

Comment: @Tim, The variational calculus method is more powerful. Shall postpone it for the time being, as it is  fait accompli. Shall soon attempt tp post what I consider to be totality of the ellipse reflection

Comment: @Tim Java should show (P,Q) as fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To get a comprehensive picture we have to find coordinates of reflection point $ M (x,y)$

Elemetary vector approach adopted as follows.

Vector $MP \rightarrow (x_p- x)  + i (y_p- y) ; $

Vector $M1  \rightarrow  (x-c,y )  + i y ; $

Vector $MQ\rightarrow (x_q- x)  + i (y_q- y) ; $

Vector $M1\rightarrow  (x+c ,y )  + i y ; $

Angle between vectors $(MQ,M1)$ = angle between vectors $(MP,M2)$;

where $(1,2)$ are abbreviated for $(F1,F2)$

So equating their cosines through dot product we get locus of all required points of incidence sought by the OP for an entire family of confocal ellipses ( for that matter all conics, when appropriate sign changes are made.)

$$ \cos \theta_q = \dfrac{ (x_q- x) (x+c) - y (y_q- y) } { \sqrt{(x_q-x)^2 + (y_q-y)^2 } \cdot  \sqrt{(x+c)^2 + y^2} }$$

$$ \cos \theta_p = \dfrac{ (x_p- x) (x-c) - y (y_p- y) } { \sqrt{(x_p-x)^2 + (y_p-y)^2 } \cdot  \sqrt{(x-c)^2 + y^2} }$$

Equation of locus of confocal ellipses used to plot is

$$ \cos \theta_q = \mp \cos \theta_p $$

However the reflection point is available only implicitly. Eighth degree (Octic?) polynomial.

Given points are $P,Q,F1,F2 $ .Wlog ellipse has x-axis horizontal. Constants used to graph ( in Mathematica ContourPlot ) below:

$$ [ (x_p,y_p),(x_q,y_q), (a,b,c)]= [ ( -4.8, 2.9), (3., 4.1), (5,3,4)] $$

Only one value of $c=4$ is represented on magenta colored ellipse:

Each square has side length = 5.

Both convex and concave reflection points ( purple and red loci ) are obtained graphically by the method here. It is possible to numerically get the reflection points by  solving the locus and ellipse profiles together (not given here).

EDIT 1:

The scheme works also when given points are inside a bigger confocal ellipse (OP did not ask for this option). Here $ (a,c) = (8,4). $  Pictured around the same rope and hump loci, for same positions of $ P,Q, F_1, F_2 $. Colors interchanged.

[image: Beam Start/End External/Internal to Ellipse]

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 1:

In other words, when the position of a point on ellipse M is correct we note that two conditions need to be satisfied:

Using  minimization of length by Fermat principle and constraint condition $( P M F_2)$ is a straight line, [$M (x,y)$ a point on ellipse, $F_2$ is focal point on the side opposite of normal in a reflection setting ] we can use a Lagrangian

$$  F(x,y)= \sqrt{(x_p- x )^2  + (y_p- y)^2} + \sqrt{(x_q- x)^2 + (y_q- y)^2} ; $$

$$ G(x,y) = \frac{y_p-y}{x_p-x} - \frac{y_ {F_2}-y}{x_{F_2}-x}, $$

since position of focus $F_2$ is known to be on a straight line i.e., in the solution we should have lines $ PMF_2, QMF_1 $ straight (and later on would be shown equally inclined to the ellipse tangent at $M$),

we should satisfy $$ \frac{F_x}{F_y} = \frac{G_x}{G_y} = -\lambda. $$

EDIT 2:

The following interesting property can be used for a possible total solution.

Just as $M$ is tangent point of contact of the given ellipse with foci $F_1,F_2$  that contains contact incident/reflected rays $PF_2,Q F_1, $ so also is  $M$ is a common tangent point of contact of a dual ellipse with foci $P,Q $  sharing the same incident/reflected rays $PF_2,Q F_1. $

This leads to an unexpected conclusion that straight line$ P F_2, Q F_1,$ and the tangent at M (red line), should be concurrent at the tangent point $M$ and more importantly also that the

*positions of $P,Q$ cannot be be assigned arbitrarily as given/fixed. If P is given, point Q must necessarily lie on straight line  $F_1 M $ .*

EDIT 3:

Schematic dual ellipses pictured in addition to the existing image.

A laser beam focused from P onto ellipse goes through Q, obeying reflection laws, which can be shown by Fermat principle. Likewise from F1 to F2 internally there is a reflection.As vertically opposite angles must be equal, $ PMQ $ must be a straight line.

[image: ContactingDualEllipses]

Comment: I understood the concept of applying Fermat principal that would give the shortest path. But I could not understand the next step. Can you please give a hint using elementary calculus ? Thanks

Comment: Try to sketch the tangent and lines of reflection and incidence which are concurrent straight lines at the required point..

Comment: Gosh! three equations!

Comment: Only 2 equations needed.

Comment: Sorry about the edit and change ( that retains essential point of first post).