Ellipse: Billard/reflection property, determine reflection point
Let A,B be two different points on an ellipse. Is there a constructive method to find points P on the ellipse, such that a light ray from A to P, reflected in the ellipse at P, meets B? I.e. such that the tangent $t_P$ and normal $n_P$ at P to the ellipse are the bisectors of the angle $\angle(A,P,B)$ at P?
As $t_P, n_P$ are the bisectors of the focal rays $PF_1, PF_2$, the line segments $\overline{AF_1}, \overline{BF_2}$ are seen at the same angle from P. But so far, I don't see a constructive method to determine P.
Any ideas? Thank you.


Seemingly, the tangents $t_A, t_B$ to the ellipse in the points A,B meet in a point Q on the normal $n_P$, and P is the base point on the ellipse of that intersection point Q. (P is the base point of the pole Q of the line AB.)
However, the basepoint of a generic point is not constructively determinable...
It is interesting, that for a given Q, its base point P would solve the reflection problem for the intersection points A,B of the ellipse with the polar of Q.

Wolfram has a completely parametrized Manipulate demonstration at https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ReflectionsInAnEllipticalRegion/

@RolandF Thank you for the link! Wolfram visualises multiple reflections for the elliptic billard. Basically, that's kind of inverse (and easier) task, as there are constructions for successive points and even for the enclosed envelope-conic.

I guess, that a construction would need at least working in 3D, eg. by using circle geometry and the cyclographic mapping,for representing wavelets like in Huygen's construction in optics.
The reason is: One of the searched-for points P is the nearest basepoint (pedal point) of Q. It is equivalent to suppose the point Q (outside the ellipse) or the points A,B, because A,B are the intersection points of the polar of Q with the ellipse. If P could be constructed for given, A,B, then P could be constructed for given Q. However, the general basepoints (and normals from Q) are not constructable.


enter image description here
Hint: To find P:
1- Draw tangents on ellipse c on point A and B, they intersect at Q.
2-Connect B to Q and draw a circle $e_1$ on diameter BQ.
3- draw a circle $c_1$ with radius QB.
Particular cases :
Case 1: P is the point of tangent of a circle center at Q equal to circle $e_1$.In this case Q, P and the point of intersection of $e_1$ with DB (E)are colinear.
Case 2: The distance between intersection of $e_1$ and BD (E ) from B is equal to BI, where I is the center of ellipse.


I tried your construction but it doesn't work. What is the purpose of circle $e_1$?

@Intelligentipauca, Thanks for response. I included two particular cases. For general, I am still working.

@sirous The normal $n_P$ does not bisect $\angle(A,Q,B)$. As P is also a pedal point of Q on the ellipse, P is the intersection of the ellipse and the Apollonian hyperbola associated to Q. The hyperbola can be drawn, but intersection is nonconstructive. An alternative is Chasles' parabola. In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641426/   user Narasimhan suggested (in his wrong "solution" there) to consider the pencil of confocal ellipses with foci A,B. One then has to find among them that ellipse which touches the given ellipse, i.e. has a full common point-tangent-element...

@Intelligentipauca sirous just presented two special cases. As I see it, circle e1 is used for Thales theorem to construct the a perpendicular from B to n_P.
I tried directly with bisectors $t_P, n_P$ and their harmonic separation on the line AB.

@ASlateff, I did not claim that $n_p$ bisects angle AQB, as you see in figure, but it definitely bisects angle APQ. At lease I could show how to construct for two particular cases. I dont know why down voter did it. At least could say the reason.

@sirous Do I understand you correctly, that your main idea of attack is to replace QA by QD? But how do you determine point D? Point D basically could be any point on circle $c_1$...?
If I understand you correctly, you want to compensate the fact, that Q is not the centre of bisection on $n_P$ for points A and B, by making Q a centre of bisection in an auxiliary triangle DQB and therefore transform the (unknown) difference of position of Q and P into a difference of angles of lines through Q?

@ASlateff, In both cases E is the mid point of BD, sos D is the reflection of B about E.
